# Search Text with dropdown suggestion in Tapestry

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tapestry

Can anyone suggest me if there is any Tapestry in-build component to "Search a Textbox with dropdown suggestion"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the auto complete mixin meet your needs?

http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/mixins/Autocomplete.html

http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart7/examples/ajax/autocompletemixin

http://tapestry.apache.org/ajax-and-zones.html